# I want to display different png's from openweather.org depending on the weather description. I wrote the if statement but how do i write it in?

Tags: python, tkinter, url, python-imaging-library, png

for example:

```
if condition == "clear" or "clear sky":
    weather_png = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png"
elif condition == "few clouds":
    weather_png = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02d@2x.png"
elif condition == "scattered clouds":
    weather_png = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03d@2x.png"
elif condition == "broken clouds" or "overcast clouds":
    weather_png = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04d@2x.png"
```

What do i write so it opens weather_png up? i imported PIL and url.request but i cant figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to use `urllib.request` module to fetch the image? It is better to state clear what you have tried and the problem you came across.

Comment: Note that `condition == "clear" or "clear sky"` is the same as `(condition == "clear") or "clear sky"`, so it will be always `True`.  What you want may be `conditiion in ("clear", "clear sky")` instead.

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64779778/5317403) help?

Comment: I figured out how to use urllib.request and how to write it in the if statement. 

condition == "clear" or "clear sky" is the same as (condition == "clear") or "clear sky", so it will be always True. What you want may be conditiion in ("clear", "clear sky") This was the final solution to make it work after that. As i am new to coding i dont really understand why that worked... 
If you feel like explaining it, it would be appreciated otherwise thanks for the tip!

Comment: A non-empty string will be evaluated as `True` in `if` statement, so `condition == "clear" or "clear sky"` will be the same as `condition == "clear" or True` and the final result will be `True` no matters what the result of `condition == "clear"` is.

Comment: Alright thanks for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard library's `webbrowser` like this:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new(weather_png)
```